# how to use the binding with kedoui's dropdownlist?

Tags: ember.js

i have drop downlist in emberjs  and i declare it like that below

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.serviceAreaList"        selectionBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.serviceAreaSelection"                                 optionLabelPath="content.ZipCode"     optionValuePath="content.ServiceAreaID"}}
```

but i want to use kendo ui's dropdownlist which i can use like below

```
<input id="dropDownList" />
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropDownList").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: [
            { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
            { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
        ]
    });
});
```

i want to use kendoui dropownlist with ember

Answer (score 0):

Try it like [wycats' examples for jqueryUI](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/11/using-sproutcore-2-0-with-jquery-ui/)

```
App.KendoSelectView = Em.Select.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        this.$().kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: ....
        });
    }
});
```

You can probably pick up the attributes for the DDL from the select properties.

Comment: that is alright but as we do selection binding in ember like "selectionBinding='App.somevariable'". value changes to undefined. so how can we achieve with kendoui.